# node version manager not changing the Node Version in Ubuntu. Stuck on system node version. How to change node version using nvm?

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm, nvm

I am trying to do

`npm install wrtc`
with node version  16.14.0

but that's not getting done. It's giving
`npm error code 1`

So I was trying to change node version to previous lts which was 14.19.0 but it's not getting changed

I did...

```
node -v
nvm list
nvm use 14.19.0 => output - ***Now using node v14.19.0 (npm v8.5.3)***
node -v (version not changed... Still 16.14.0

nvm list - shows the arrow mark '->' still on system
```

Comment: What is the ouput of ``nvm list``? Have you installed node version 14.19.0 with ``nvm install 14.19.0``?

Comment: Yes 
I have done that

That's why after giving
-> nvm use 14.19.0 
           Output is - ***Now using node v14.19.0 (npm v8.5.3)***

Answer (score 1):

> Are you following these steps?
> Please make sure that your npm version is correctly installed according to your node version.

[image]